# Otimizar consulta MySQL com Sub Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, order-by, select-limit

Estava com um problema de lentidão em um select conforme abaixo:

```
    select 
      vendas.codigo, vendas.cartao_tipo, vendas.valor, 
      vendas.datavenda, venda.autorizacao,
      cliente.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.cpf,
      cartao.numero_final, cartao.nome,
      plano.nome, plano.max_parcela
    from mv_vendas vendas
    inner join mv_clientes clientes on(clientes.codigo = vendas.cli_codigo)
    left join mv_cartoes cartao on(cartao.tipo = vendas.cartao_tipo)
    left join mv_planos plano on(plano.codigo = vendas.plano_codigo)
    where (vendas.datavenda between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31')
      and(vendas.status = 'sucesso')
    order by vendas.datavenda desc
    limit 100,50
```

Esse SELECT numa tabela de 150 mil registros (com os devidos index nos campos agregados) demora 2.600s na minha maquina local, quando coloco no servidor demora 0,312s, uma enorme diferença

Levando em conta que meu servidor é um Xeon 8 Núcleos e 16GB de Memoria com SSD no inicio acabei aceitando a diferença...

Mas aí comecei a pensar, espere aí... meu notebook é um i5 com 8GB de memória e SSD, não pode demorar tanto assim... foi aí que comecei a fazer testes de SQL para ver se melhorava o resultado na minha máquina, porque 150 mil registros numa tabela é quase nada... eu já trabalhei com DBF com 10 milhões de registros e era quase instantâneo...

Comecei a ver que o MySQL estava lendo a tabela toda pra me trazer o resultado do order by e limit, porque quando eu os tirava ficava muito mais rápido.

Mas como eu preciso paginar e trazer ordenado por data decrescente então cheguei no seguinte SELECT:

```
    select 
      vendas.codigo, vendas.cartao_tipo, vendas.valor, 
      vendas.datavenda, venda.autorizacao,
      cliente.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.cpf,
      cartao.numero_final, cartao.nome,
      plano.nome, plano.max_parcela
    from( 
      select * from mv_vendas
      where (datavenda between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31')
        and(status = 'sucesso')
      order by datavenda desc
      limit 100,50
    ) as vendas
    inner join mv_clientes clientes on(clientes.codigo = vendas.cli_codigo)
    left join mv_cartoes cartao on(cartao.tipo = vendas.cartao_tipo)
    left join mv_planos plano on(plano.codigo = vendas.plano_codigo)
```

Analisando, faz sentido porque agora estou buscando na tabela mv_vendas somente o que eu realmente preciso e depois junto os dados das tabelas agregadas

Resultado: Na minha maquina ele faz o SELECT em 0,035s e no servidor 0,032s

Estou colocando aqui no Stack para receber as criticas dos colegas para saber se estou no caminho certo, porque estou longe de ser um DBA, mas quero tirar o melhor que eu puder da base de dados em se tratando de tempo de busca.

Se tiverem sugestões para que eu possa melhorar esse SELECT ai, sou todo ouvidos.

Obs. As tabelas mv_cartoes e mv_planos nem sempre terão os registros de vendas por isso o uso do left.

Comment: Não sou expert em DB, mas acho que pra alguém conseguir te responder precisará saber 1) como são as tabelas; 2) como está o plano de execução da query; 3) qual o SGBD. A propósito, o texto ficou confuso, Sua segunda query retorna o que você quer ou falta algo?

Comment: As duas retornam o que eu preciso, o problema é só o tempo de resposta... e o SGDB é o MySQL

Comment: Claramente o tempo de resposta está bom, principalmente comparando com a primera query. Não entendi a dúvida, parece que você fez a pergunta e a resposta juntas.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ter certeza de que estou no caminho certo, porque as vezes pensamos que um select está bom pelo tempo de resposta, mas o passar do tempo pode mostrar que esse select não traria o resultado correto da base, deixando algum registro para traz, por isso postei.